# Web HttpRequest method in asp.net

Tags: c#, json, web-services, json.net

**My C# class**

```
public class City
{
    public int City_id { get; set; }  
    public string City_name { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public City[] lstCitiesResult { get; set; }
}
```

**Web Request**

```
string url = "my url";          
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

// provide your ID And Password for proxy
request.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(XXXX);

WebResponse ws = request.GetResponse();

DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer =
               new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Model>));

List<Model> dataList =
 (List<Model>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(ws.GetResponseStream());

string result = "";

foreach (var data1 in dataList)
{
    result = result + data1.lstCitiesResult.ToString();
}

TextBox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

My error: I got null in datalist...what i do?

Comment: Well `result` can't be null because you initialize it to an empty string and add non-null strings to it.  Is it just empty?  Have you run it in debugger?

Comment: Inspect the text from `ws.GetResponseStream()` in debugger and see if it matches the Json format you'd expect for a list of that class.

Comment: Do you need to call GetResponse()?  See the example at [WebRequest doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)